# $\sqrt{a_1}+\ldots+\sqrt a_n$ is a root of this polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I don't know how to solve this question:

> Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be no perfect square natural numbers. I want to
>   show that
>
> $$\sqrt{a_1}+\ldots+\sqrt a_n$$
>
> is a root of a polynomious of degree $2^n$ with integer coefficients
>   such that the one with higher degree is $1$.

How can I use the fact they aren't perfect squares to solve this question?

**EDIT**

What I have done so far:

*For n=1:*

$f(x)=(x-\sqrt{a_1})(x+\sqrt{a_1})=x^2-a_1$

*For n=2*

$$f(x)=(x-\sqrt{a_1}-\sqrt{a_2})(x+\sqrt{a_1}+\sqrt{a_2})(x^2-a_1-a_2+2\sqrt{a_1}\sqrt{a_2})$$

How can I generalize it?

Comment: You probably won't use the fact they aren't perfect squares, because the claim still holds even if some of them are perfect squares.  What have you tried so far?  Can you prove it for $n=1$?  $n=2$?

Comment: Note that this is an upper bound, for example when some of the a's are equal.

Comment: @ErickWong see my edit please

Comment: @sirous it seems you're having problems with mathjax, could you edit your comment please

Comment: Consider simple form for polynomial as:$$[ (x^2-a)(x^2-b)(x^2-3).....to k terms)]$$ Where $ k =2^{n-1}$, then the degree of power of polynomial  will be $2_˟ {2^{n-1}}=2^n$. The roots are $(x_1=a^{0.5}, x_2=b^{0.5} ...$.

Comment: @sirous thank you for your comment. However I can't understand why this implies the sum of the $\sqrt{a_i}$ are solutions of this equation and why the coefficients are integers

Comment: Just consider the polynomial $\prod (x-\beta)$ where $\beta=\pm\sqrt{a_1}\pm\ldots\pm\sqrt{a_n}$ ranges over all the possible choices of $\pm$. This clearly is a monic polynomial vanishing at $\sqrt{a_1}+\ldots+\sqrt{a_n}$. You just have to prove that its coefficients belong to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: user42912. Ok consider $ax^2 +bx+c$ for each term If $(b^2 -4.a.c)$ is not perfect square then the root is something like $m ± t^{0.5}$ where the coefficients of polynomial will be integers.

Comment: user42912, Note that $(ax^2+bx+c)^k$ may have rational coefficient, but you do not have this case here; you multiply k different polynomial of second degree and there is no rational coefficient in final product!